# How to disconnect a realtime database from my app and use a new realtime database of a new project?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my mainactivity code :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var name:EditText
    lateinit var email:EditText
    lateinit var password:EditText
    lateinit var login:Button
    lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        name=findViewById(R.id.name)
        email=findViewById(R.id.emailid)
        password=findViewById(R.id.password)
        login=findViewById(R.id.login)
        databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("\n" +
                "\n" +
                "https://test2-3e833-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/")
        login.setOnClickListener()
        {
            val name :String=name.text.toString()
            val email:String=email.text.toString()
            val password:String=password.text.toString()

            databaseReference.child("users").child(name).child("Email").setValue(email)
            databaseReference.child("users").child(name).child("password").setValue(password)

            Toast.makeText(this,"Database write successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val a=Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(a)
        }
    }
}
```

I have added all dependencies and the JSON file and I want to change the real-time database of my app entirely to a new database of a new project in firebase. cause I did something wrong in the current realtime database.

This is the logcat while launching the app :

*https://test2-3e833-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/) passed to getReference().  URL was expected to match configured Database URL: https://test1-340e5-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReferenceFromUrl(FirebaseDatabase.java:214)
at com.example.realtimefirebasetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:26)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8153)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8137)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3698)
... 11 more*

**test 2 is the new database that I want to use and test 1 is the old database**

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to point to a new Realtime Database instance is to pass its URL in the code like this:

```
databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("new URL here").getReference();
```

If the mistake was in the data in your database, you can of course also simply delete all data from the database and start from scratch.

Comment: I have tried to change the url of the reference and I have also replaced the json file(which is the primary file to connect the database with the app).. but my app is not even starting after launching it.. crashes as soon as the app launches.

Comment: If the app crashes, it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat output. Please find those, and add them to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it.

Comment: But if i just change to the previous URL then the app is working fine. Even if I have already changed the json file as per as  the new project.

Comment: Done. Check out the logcat file.

Comment: From that error message it looks like your `google-service.json` doesn't have the same database URL as what you specify in your code. I recommend either removing the JSON file, or ensuring you download the JSON file from the same project as you're trying to specify in the code.

Comment: i have manually deleted the previous json file and the dependencies as well of the test 1 database and added the new json file and the dependencies once again for the test 2(new realtime database)